# block ram (BRAM) read and write using different clocks

Tags: vhdl

I am relatively new to some advanced VHDL programming and have a problem i have been facing for a while. 
I will try to be very thorough in my problem description.

I am using a Digilent Nexys-3 board with SPARTAN - 6 FPGA

Here is what i am trying to implement:

- Read data from ADC SPI bus and store it into the BRAM.
- For this i instantiate a block RAM using a memory IP core generator

  ```
  ADC_BRAM: bram
  port map( ..
            ..
            addra => addra,
            dina => ADC_DATA,
            ..
            ..
           );
  ```

The addra, ADC_DATA (data on SPI bus stored into a std_logic_vector) is assigned during the "read_adc" state of the FSM in the ADC module.

- After the ADC has sampled 100 points I stop writing into the BRAM

  ```
  main: process(clk)
  begin
  if(rising_edge(clk)) then

  case state is

  when  read_adc =>
  .....   
  .....   
  .....   
  if(addra < "1100100") then
  .....   
     <some code>  
     addra <= addra + 1;
  .....            
  elsif (addra = "1100100") then
     state <= endofconversion;
  end if;

  when endofconversion =>
      addra <= "00000000";
      wea   <= "0"; -- write enable for BRAM

      state <= read_bram;
  ```
- Next, i want to access the data from the BRAM and send it using USB-UART.
- From what i understand all the BRAM's are synchronous and thus have to be implemented with process(clk,reset).
- Currently i have implemented the state " read_bram" under the same process as mentioned above

  ```
  main: process(clk)
  begin
  if(rising_edge(clk)) then

  case state is

  <some code> 

  when endofconversion =>
      addra <= "00000000";
      wea   <= "0"; -- write enable for BRAM

      state <= read_bram;

  when read_bram =>
  .... 
  <some code>
  ....
  end case;
  ```
- Now the UART clock needs to be much slower than the rate at which ADC has been read.

My question is " ***How do i implement the read operation of the BRAM using a much slower clock, which will ensure proper functioning of the UART" ?***

I also tried another approach where the BRAM module is defined in the top level file and i send the " addra, ADC_DATA" generated from the ADC module into the port map of the BRAM module.

Now, on the top level if i create a slower clock to read the data ("douta") from the BRAM and send it to UART, i need to generate "addra"  in this process and send it to BRAM port "addra"

This causes issues of " multiple drivers " connected to signal "addra", as its values changes in the "process()"  of both the ADC module (faster clock) and the top level module (slower clock).

Please help me out. I can provide more info if the problem description is not clear.

***TLDR; How can i use 2 separate clocks while implementing synchronous memory BRAM
 - "faster clock => write into BRAM" -- based on ADC sampling rate
 - " slower clock => read from BRAM"  -- based on UART clk (slower BAUD rate than ADC sampling speed)***

Comment: Do you really need a RAM? It seems a FIFO would fit your application better. In any case, you can use a dual-port RAM (or FIFO) with independant clock for each port. Thus, you would write on port A and read on port B.

Comment: Maybe our open-source FIFOs (incl. a cross-clock capable FIFO [fifo_ic_got](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/fifo/fifo_ic_got.vhdl)) can help you out... This FIFO is implemented on top of our Simple-Dual-Port On-Chip RAM ([ocram_sdp](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/mem/ocram/ocram_sdp.vhdl), which abstracts different FPGA platform specific implementations like BlockRAM, LUT-RAM, DirstributedRAM into one module. A SDP-RAM has one write port and one read port, with independently clocked interfaces.

Comment: Thanks you @JonathanDrolet : A simple dual port BRAM solved my issue.